# EF 7 Identity Insert Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have to be able to set the primary key of the entities I am trying to add in my list "final_zones". I have a controller constructor as follows:

```
    public UtilController(CFETSContext context)
    {
        _context = context; 
    }
     ......Then in a web api method.........
        using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CFETSWeb].[dbo].[Zone] ON");             

            _context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }


       using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {             
            _context.Zones.AddRange(final_zones);
            _context.SaveChanges(); //ERROR HERE
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get IDENTITY_INSERT to turn on. I get the following error:

```
{"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Zone' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}
```

I just can't seem to get it to turn off. I can add entities to my DB in the controller, so I know everything else is working. I have tried doing this without a transaction as well with the same result.

```
 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CFETSWeb].[dbo].[Zone] ON"); 
_context.Zones.AddRange(final_zones);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Any ideas? I am at a loss for what to try next. Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you decorated/configured the primary key property of zone model as key?

Comment: See this: http://blog.robertobonini.com/2014/10/09/entity-framework-with-identity-insert/

Comment: Yes.


        [Key]
        public int ZoneId { get; set; }

Comment: @JohnEdwards - Could you try specifying (not needed as per naming convention) [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] as well?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it with the following:

```
       using (var dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CFETSWeb].[dbo].[Zone] ON");
                _context.Zones.AddRange(final_zones);
                _context.SaveChanges();          

                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

**NOTE:** You HAVE to do this per table. IDENTITY_INSERT can only be set for 1 table at a time it seems, so you can do it this way or toggle it to OFF in the same transaction.

Also, IDENTITY_INSERT has to be in a transaction, as it only stays on for the duration of a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` statement is scoped to one SQL session, which is practically equivalent to one set of statements that is sent over an open connection.

However, by default, an EF context will open and close a connection for each single statement with database interaction it executes. So after the `ExecuteSqlCommand` statement, the connection is closed, and the `IDENTITY_INSERT` is reset.

Now it's a somewhat hidden feature that EF *won't close a connection* if you open it before the context executes statements. So if you do this ...

```
try
{
    _context.Database.Connection.Open();
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CFETSWeb].[dbo].[Zone] ON");
    _context.Zones.AddRange(final_zones);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
finally
{
    _context.Database.Connection.Close();
}
```

... you'll notice that the `IDENTITY_INSERT` setting will "survive" the `ExecuteSqlCommand` statement.