# Change tracker won't assign correct subsequent ID to a newly inserted entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a new .NET Core project from the `webapi` template and added a model class:

```
public class Todo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My context class:

```
public SoContext: DbContext {
    public SoContext(DbContextOptions<SoContext> options) { base(options); }
    public DbSet<Todo> Todos { get; set; }
}
```

I have registered the context like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("SO"));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I thought I'd seed the context like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, SoContext context)
{
    app.UseMvc();
    context.Todos.Add(new Todo() { Id = 1, Name = "1" });
    context.SaveChanges(); // This works okay!
}
```

And it works okay… But then in my request handler, or even directly after in `Configure`, when I run this:

```
context.Todos.Add(new Todo() { Name = "non-seed" });
context.SaveChanges(); // Uh - oh
```

I get:

> The instance of entity type 'Todo' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

The way I see it the change tracker should have figured out to assign the ID of `2` to the `non-seed` `Todo`, no? Why isn't it so?

I tried to use `Attach` instead of add for the entity with the key, even though it doesn't make any sense, and sure enough it made no difference.

[Here's a GitHub repository that demonstrates the problem](https://github.com/TomasHubelbauer/ef-key-problem)

Comment: Does it work for `new Todo() { Id = 2, Name = "non-seed" }`?

Comment: It doesn't. I enabled sensitive logging and it tells me the conflicting ID is `1`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't recognize you're working with EF 2.0.

Comment: No need to apologize. I ought to have mentioned it - I just wasn't aware this might have been different in v 1.x.

Comment: I'm not sure about /w in-memory databases but it looks like you are missing the attribute to inform EF that the ID column is auto-generated.. "    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: This now works in .NET Core 3.0! [You can see a showcase here](https://github.com/TomasHubelbauer/ef-ids-atop-seeded-ids).

I got an answer to this question in a [comment in the GitHub repository for `EntityFrameworkCore`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9683#issuecomment-326833336).

> When using database-generated keys at the same time as keys chosen by the application it is the responsibility of the application to not choose keys that collide with those generated by the database.

This means that at the moment, either the database is seeded with entities lacking keys (so any relationships need to be set up using navigation properties rather than the IDs) or using raw SQL and letting FE pick up on an already seeded database (thanks, @Nicolaus - although this won't work for in-memory I think).

> We could make the key generator in the in-memory database smarter, so leaving this open to discuss in triage, but I think even if we decide to do so, it will likely be low priority.

Comment: If you want your Context be seeded with explicit Id, you may use "Identity Insert on" combined with an transaction with an Transaction.

Comment: You're thinking seed it in SQL and then have EF pick up on an already seeded database, right? Good idea as well, but I don't have a SQL seed and the format that I have is more amendable to to navigation property approach. Either way, thank you. Edited.

Comment: No I'm not thinking about seed with SQL look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023922/ef-7-identity-insert-issue

Comment: You're still using `ExecuteSqlCommand` which may not be supported with in-memory. :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer to say it now works in .NET Core 3.0!