# How can I set the Identity Insert on using DBContext as I'm trying to add values(supposed to be exactly same) from a different table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Database first approach.

My destination table is first truncated using RemoveRange() and then data is transferred from source table using `Destination.Tables.AddRange(Source.Tables);`

All other column data is copied properly. But 'Id' field is populated from a larger no. I want the Id field to be same. That's why I'm trying to set identity insert on.

I tried to follow this tutorial but it doesn't work for me
http://blog.robertobonini.com/2014/10/09/entity-framework-with-identity-insert/

**table.cs**

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

**Inside function**

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            {
                using (var Destination = new DestinationEntities(NewconnDestination))
                {
                    using (var Source = new SourceEntities(NewconnSource))
                    {

                        Source.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                        Source.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                        Destination.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[Table] ON");
                        Destination.Tables.AddRange(Source.Tables);
                        SaveChanges(Destination);
                        Destination.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[Table] OFF");
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                } }
```

These are my column properties on the table
[Id properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0zUU.png)

Is there something else required? Or any other method to achieve this?

This is the issue. I need Id column to be same in both tables.
Source Table
[ID column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDdkm.png)
Destination Table
[ID column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA3nW.png)

***.Net version: 4.5 Entity framework: 6.1.3***

Comment: What was the error happened?

Comment: Please state your issue properly.

Comment: `it doesn't work for me` how? What error you are getting?

Comment: I need the 'Id' column in destination table to be exactly same as 'Id' column in source table even though it is an identity field.

Comment: AddRange() autogenerates the Id from a different number, so the Id field mismatches

Comment: No chance if the property has `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. EF won't ever include the ID value in the insert statement. If they aren't and the database has identity columns (which it apparently has), you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39027882/861716).

Comment: Since you're already using it, You could just run the `ExecuteSqlCommand` to insert/select the data across as well. i.e. `ExecuteSqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO TABLE(IdentityColumn,ANotherCOlumn) SELECT IdentityColumn,ANothercolumn from SOURCETABLE")`

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial you linked, the author states:

> All the primary keys that you want to Force to be inserted should be changed to `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` This ensures that EF will not try and change the values and will simply insert them with the rest of the data.

EDIT:

I tried this setup and it worked:     (Thanks to Gert Arnold.)

ItemID is the identity column of the table ItemTable.

```
[Table("ItemTable")]
public partial class ItemTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ItemTable> ItemsList = new List<ItemTable>
        {
            new ItemTable { ItemID=1, ItemName="one" },
            new ItemTable { ItemID=2, ItemName="two" },
            new ItemTable { ItemID=3, ItemName="three" }
        };

        TestDbContext testDbContext = new TestDbContext();

        try
        {
            testDbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            testDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestDB].[dbo].[ItemTable] ON");
            testDbContext.ItemTables.AddRange(ItemsList);
            testDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        finally
        {
            testDbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't help because the database has identity columns.

Comment: I used [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] , but it doesn't help.

Comment: If I read and understand Gerd Arnolds corresponding answer from another question, that he linked to, correctly ...

then it is also necessary that you manually open and close your connection:

Destination.Database.Connection.Open()
and
Destination.Database.Connection.Close()

otherwise your "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON" is useless because your DbContext opens and closes the connection just for that command and on the next command SET_IDENTITY is reset to OFF

let me know if that was the solution ... if so, i will edit my answer

Comment: I am getting this exception after I made these changes..`Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Table' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.`

Comment: Then I think the only way to get your ID from source referenced in destination is by storing it in a field which isn't the identity. ... Is the content in both tables, and hence all the ID's, the same or is there data in one of them that isn't mirrored?

Comment: I can't use this ItemList because in this scenario I have more than thousands of records and I cannot initialize each ItemID separately. Also, I cannot make the ID field in the destination table as non-identity, because it is a backup and from that table the data will be restored to source table, if data is lost/damaged, that's why it needs to be mirror image of source database(both schema and data).

Comment: You don't have to initialize each ID, just generate the List from the data you get out of your source table. ..... Another way of generating a backup from a table could be to just copy the whole, or part of the table with SQL, and every time you do a backup just drop the last backup table.  Would this be a possible solution?

Comment: The ID mismatch was happening because of update functionality(RemoveRange() and AddRange() for the recently updated rows. So I discarded RemoveRange and now I'm changing  source table values ,getting data through destination table values(column wise) and that has worked for me.

Comment: I couldn't copy the whole DB because the code was breaking (due to a very large no. of records), so I did selective backup