# Adding entities to database with negative IDs Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I would like to add some of my special entities with negative IDs to my SQL database using Entity Framework 6. The problem is, if I add some entity like:

```
DbSet.Add(new MyEntity() { Id = -12, Name = "Foo", Title = "Bar" });
```

with **SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE ON** I end up having an entity with **Id = 12**. The Id is written positive in the database while I want it to be negative.
I tested entering negative IDs with raw SQL and it works well. So I assume it has something to do with EF6.

EDIT:
Some piece of code:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db].[dbo].[table] ON");
dbSet.AddOrUpdate(e => e.Id, entities);
//dbSet.AddRange(entities);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db].[dbo].[table] OFF");
```

Where **entities** are the objects with **Id = -x**. Neither of **AddOrUpdate** nor **AddRange** works with negative IDs. The results are placed in the database with positive IDs. However the **AddOrUpdate** method suspects the difference between the input entities and the entitites already in the database so it doesn't "Update" the entities with positive IDs. Instead, it adds the entities normally as if I am using **AddRange**. To be more clear, this only happens if the positive versions of my negative IDs are present in the database. (Which is not my problem, I just want to add entities with negative IDs.) Btw, the Id fields in the entities are of type int.

Comment: What dotnet type has the `Id` property in your entitiy?

Comment: How do you set identity insert on? You really need to show the full code handling the insert.

Comment: @GertArnold I edited the post. Everything works fine I guess it's just a layer of procession in EF6 which doesn't accept negative int identifiers.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt It is System.Int32, AKA int.

Comment: As I assumed, you run the commands in separate sessions. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39023922/861716.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks but transactions are automatically managed inside AddOrUpdate methods. I may have not described my problem well (Considering how hard it is to describe the matter.) I'm able to add an entity with Id = 2020, but if I try to add an entity with Id = -2020 (Negative) it is added as if Id = 2020.

Comment: OK, assuming this first issue, I didn't give it much thought. But now I wonder, how do you configure this in EF? Do you have an identity column in the database but no database-generated option in EF?

Comment: @GertArnold I configure my models manually in the code using Model.HasKey(m => m.Id).

Comment: So EF assumes it's identity and the key value is not in the insert statement. Could you check that?

Comment: @GertArnold Would you please describe what exactly should I do to check it?